# Configure pandoc to extract media to different folder

Tags: pandoc

I use pandoc to convert `docx` to `markdown` with the following:

`pandoc -f docx -t markdown --extract-media="pandoc-output/$filename/" -o "pandoc-output/$filename/full.md" "$fullfile"`

Which works OK. However, the media is stored in:

`pandoc-output/$filename/media/`

I want the media to be stored in

`/pandoc-output/media/$filename/`

Is this possible?

***UPDATE***

I ended up with a `sed` command to search and replace the offending lines together with a `mv` to the proper directory.

`gsed -i -r "s/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)\/pandoc-output\/media\/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/\/public\/media\/\1\/\2/" $ROOTDIR"$d"_"$filename.html.md"`

Comment: This has been asked in the past a few times, including [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/1986).  The short answer is that  you can use a shell command to move the files by hand ("mv DIR/media DIR/img"). Then, you would need to write a quick filter so the files link to the correct location. A bit cumbersome so maybe not worth it unless you *really* need it.